# Sorting numbers in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

I want to sort my table id numbers on descending order.
When user clicks on sort text, the sort must work, but I can't find solution for this problem.
Here is my JS code...
Got one more issue: When deleting table rows, delete function doesn't removing last tr element.

```
$(function(){
    var tableHead =
        "<table>" +
            "<tr>" +
             "<th class='sort'>Id sort</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Birthday</th><th>Filter</th><th class='addList'>+</th>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "</table>";

    $('body').html(tableHead);

    var name = "<input type='text' class='name' placeholder='First name'>";
    var surname = "<input type='text' class='surname' placeholder='Surname'>";
    var bDayDate ="<input type='date' class='bDayDate' placeholder='Bday'>";
    var del = "Delete";
    var addList = $('.addList');
    var idNum = 0;
    var arrNum= [];

    addList.on("click", function(){
        idNum++;
       var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            var td = $("<td></td>");
            tr.append(td);

            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    td.addClass('num' + idNum);
                    td.html(idNum);
                break;
                case 1: td.html(name);
                break;
                case 2: td.html(surname);
                break;
                case 3: td.html(bDayDate);
                break;
                case 4: td.html(1);
                break;
                case 5:
                    td.addClass('delete');
                    td.html(del);
                break;
                default:
                    return "OooPs!!";
            }
        }

        $('.sort').on("click", function(){
            arrNum.push(idNum);
            arrNum.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
            for(var j = 0; j < arrNum.length; j++){
                $('.num'+j).html(arrNum[j])
            }
        });

        $('.delete').on("click", function(){
           $(this).parent().remove();

        });

        $('table').append(tr);
    });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, nicely expressed first post. You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your script, but the one you asked about (sorting).

arrNum.push(idNum); - this is called once on click on sort

To fix it move it in addList click closure.

Your last line issue comes from the fact that you add the delete event BEFORE actually appending the row.

Also another last line issue for sorting is related with the fact that you count your elements starting with 1, while your loop goes from 0 ($('.num'+j).html(arrNum[j]) -> need to add a +1).

The code that solves all you asked about below:

```js
$(function(){
    var tableHead =
        "<table>" +
            "<tr>" +
             "<th class='sort'>Id sort</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Birthday</th><th>Filter</th><th class='addList'>+</th>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "</table>";

    $('body').html(tableHead);

    var name = "<input type='text' class='name' placeholder='First name'>";
    var surname = "<input type='text' class='surname' placeholder='Surname'>";
    var bDayDate ="<input type='date' class='bDayDate' placeholder='Bday'>";
    var del = "Delete";
    var addList = $('.addList');
    var idNum = 0;
    var arrNum= [];

    addList.on("click", function(){
        idNum++;
        arrNum.push(idNum);
       var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            var td = $("<td></td>");
            tr.append(td);

            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    td.addClass('num' + idNum);
                    td.addClass('numHere');
                    td.html(idNum);
                break;
                case 1: td.html(name);
                break;
                case 2: td.html(surname);
                break;
                case 3: td.html(bDayDate);
                break;
                case 4: td.html(1);
                break;
                case 5:
                    td.addClass('delete');
                    td.html(del);
                break;
                default:
                    return "OooPs!!";
            }
        }        

        $('table').append(tr);               

        $('.delete').on("click", function() {
           $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    
    $('.sort').on("click", function(){    
      arrNum.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
      for(var j = 0; j < arrNum.length; j++){
        $('.num'+(j + 1)).html(arrNum[j])
      }
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**BUT**: There are also other important issues. An example would be that you are adding events each time you click "+". The consequence is that if you add 99999 rows you will do 99999 sortings when you click sort (just add a console.log and check :) ). The result is correct but you are killing resources with no use. My suggestion is to rewrite it a bit if is something you actually want to use. If is a homework or something... is ok.

Comment: thank you for reply, but during sorting i need to sort all row not jus only numbers,
but your answer gave me some new ideas)))

Comment: I was expecting that... as I said I only solved what you asked for :). If you need help with something else post the question :). My suggestion was to approach this differently. Instead of changing values you could remake elements in dom. I would create a container, keep data in an array (like you did) - you can also get it back from html but keeping it in js helps a bit unless you have memory issues - and each time someone clicks whatever you operate on the array, empty container and create everything again. Of course there may be better approaches depending on goal (that is just easiest).